# Error when opening excel files through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Have an excel file that imports other excel files, however when I open one of the files, it is corrupt and says...

"We found a problem with some content... blah blah... recover as much as we can.. yes or no?"

My code is the below and it currently opens the file and closes it, I think it is getting stuck at the error message. Any ideas?

```
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Workbooks.Open (ARFile), UpdateLinks:=Yes
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Edit - I condensed the code to just target the file and it opens the file then says "Method Open of Object Workbooks' Failed" and closes

```
Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\bob\Desktop\Client\Project\D-F - All 
Reports_3018489300_030117_103117 .xlsx")
```

Comment: Just taking a wild guess at first glance, Did you check the file name for extra spaces ? I noticed this on the last line: `17 .xlsx` which looks like an extra space, or possibly `D-F - All `. Just making sure. Did you try stepping through the code with F8 ? Are you using `Option Explicit` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the corruptload option:

```
Workbooks.Open (ARFile), UpdateLinks:=Yes, corruptload:=xlRepairFile
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to open each file

Comment: I've amended the solution to meet that requirement. Add the corruptload option.